# How to create model with 2 columns unique together and autoincrement?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I have two columns in my Invoice model in Django:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    use_in_migrations = True

    year = models.CharField(max_length=16, default='')
    index = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

with which I want to achieve in the database this sequence:

```
...
2020, 134
2020, 135
2021, 1
2021, 2
...
```

First I tried to add

```
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['prefix', 'index']]
```

so I will be sure that I get always unique row values in columns.
The issue is that with PostgreSQL, this creates this sequence:

```
...
2020, 134
2020, 135
2021, 136
2021, 137
...
```

Any solution how to solve this in Django?
I am using Django 2.2.

-----EDIT-----

After comments I manually reset the index of the first 2021 instance and I added that this code to the model:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # try to save the instance so the index is ordered within prefixes (years)
        # that means- a new year starts new indexing from 1
        saved = False
        self.prefix = str(date.today().year)
        if self.index == 0:
            while not saved:
                try:
                    obj = self.__class__.objects.filter(prefix=self.prefix).last()
                    if obj is None:
                        self.index = 1
                    else:
                        self.index = obj.index + 1
                    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
                    saved = True
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
        if not saved:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # save anyway
```

That surprisingly creates a sequence

```
...
2020, 134
2020, 135
2021, 1
2021, 4
2021, 7
...
```

Comment: There is not trick here, you need to override save() method and check maximum value of index for your "year" value and add 1 to it...

Comment: Hi @BriseBalloches, if I do that, what happens with the unique_together:
1. it takes the latest index, which is index of himself
2. increments to one
3. super().save(...) also increments once again
At the end, I end up with indexes N, N + 3, N + 6...
If I remove the unique_together, I give up the possibility to check the uniqueness, where a race conditions (two independent instances of object being created in the same time) can cause to have the same prefix/index value.

Comment: 1. how is it the index of himself ? It's the previous created instance index. Check if None then default to 0. 2. Increment, so far, it's (index + 1). 3. How does super().save() increments the index ? I don't see it as any incrementation in your model, it's a simple IntegerField.

Comment: @BriseBalloches I described that in the post.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand why it adds 3 each time. If you can, you should use a debugger to track index changes because it makes no sense that super.save adds 1 as well as taking the last created instance index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would try :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # try to save the instance so the index is ordered within prefixes (years)
    # that means- a new year starts new indexing from 1
    self.prefix = str(date.today().year)
    if self.index == 0:
        latest_index = Invoice.objects.filter(prefix=self.prefix).latest('index')
        self.index = latest_index.index + 1 if latest_index else 1
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```